# Rank of Coxeter matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory, coxeter-groups, quivers

Let $Q$ be a quiver and $\Phi_Q$ be the Coxeter matrix of $Q$.
Then $\Phi_Q\pm I$ are full-rank?

Comment: No. You can simply take the Coxeter matrix $\Phi_Q = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, so $\Phi_Q + I$ has rank $1$.